# Accessing array inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to access array inside array in php
my array structure is as follow.

```
$jsonobject = array();
$jsonobject['name'] = "jay";

$jsonobject['exp'] = array();
$jsonobject['exp'][] = array(
    'exp_typ' => "pay",
    'inv' => array(
        array(
            'invoicenum' => "1",
            'idate' => "1/1/2017",
            "itms" => array(
                array(
                    "itm_det" => array(
                        'rate' => 1000,
                        'discount' => 5,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

From above array I want to access idate and discount value.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: If you `print_r($jsonobject)` you will see exactly what keys you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing array values are explained in [PHP Documentation for Arrays.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
Look at example 6

In your case it usage will looks this:

```
$idate = $jsonobject['exp'][0]['inv'][0][itms];
$discount = $idate['itms'][0]['tim_det']['discount];
```

Comment: @Cool_Ashish so, please vote up my answer and mark as useful. ;)